# Threads in Perl: order of detach()

Tags: multithreading, perl, sleep

I am trying to get into Perl's use of threads. Reading the [documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlthrtut.html#Ignoring-A-Thread) I came across the following code:

```
use threads;

my $thr = threads->create(\&sub1);   # Spawn the thread
$thr->detach();   # Now we officially don't care any more

sleep(15);        # Let thread run for awhile

sub sub1 {
    my $count = 0;
    while (1) {
        $count++;
        print("\$count is $count\n");
        sleep(1);
    }
}
```

The goal, it seems, would be to create one thread running sub1 for 15 seconds, and in the mean time print some strings. However, I don't think I understand what's going on at the end of the programme.

First of all, `detach()` is defined as follows:

> Once a thread is detached, **it'll run until it's finished**; then Perl
>   will clean up after it automatically.

However, when does the subroutine finish? `while(1)` never finishes. Nor do I find any information in [`sleep()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sleep.html) that it'd cause to break a loop. On top of that, from the point we detach we are 'waiting for the script to finish and then clean it up' for 15 seconds, so if we are *waiting* for the subroutine to finish, why do we need `sleep()` in the main script? The position is awkward to me; it suggests that the main programme sleeps for 15 seconds. But what is the point of that? The main programme (thread?) sleeps while the sub-thread keeps running, but how is the subroutine then terminated?

I guess the idea is that after `sleep`-ing is done, the subroutine ends, after which we can detach/clean up. But how is this syntactically clear? Where in the definition of sleep is it said that `sleep` terminates a subroutine (and why), and how does it know which one to terminate in case there are more than one threads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`detach` a thread means "I don't care any more", and that does actually mean when your process exits, the thread will error and terminate.

Practically speaking - I don't think you ever want to detach a thread in perl - just add a `join` at the end of your code, so it can exit cleanly, and signal it via a semaphore or `Thread::Queue` in order to terminate.

```
$_ -> join for threads -> list;
```

Will do the trick.

That code example - in my opinion - is a bad example. It's just plain messy to `sleep` so a detached thread has a chance to complete, when you could just `join` and *know* that it's finished. This is especially true of `perl` threads, which it's deceptive to assume they're lightweight, and so can be trivially started (and `detached`). If you're ever spawning enough that the overhead of `join`ing them is too high, then you're using perl threads wrong, and probably should `fork` instead.

You're quite right - the thread will never terminate, and so you code will always have a 'dirty' exit.

So instead I'd rewrite:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use threads;
use threads::shared;

my $run : shared;
$run = 1;

sub sub1 {
   my $count = 0;
   while ($run) {
      $count++;
      print("\$count is $count\n");
      sleep(1);
   }
   print "Terminating\n";
}


my $thr = threads->create( \&sub1 );    # Spawn the thread

sleep(15);                               # Let thread run for awhile
$run = 0;
$thr->join;
```

That way your main signals the thread to say "I'm done" and waits for it to finish it's current loop.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand join. It is represented as a method that can 'watch' the thread separate from the main thread. Would this mean that you could write the joi line before the sleep line, resulting in the same behaviour? Or is join blocking the main programme? Also, what if a thread completes before `join` is called? Does it result in an error? Is the return value lost? (Please tell me if the questions are too broad, then I 'll create a new question.)

Comment: `join` is a blocking call. It'll wait until thread completion. If the thread completes first, then that's fine - `join` just reaps it and gets the return code (much like `waitpid` does)

Comment: Okay, thanks, and what about the second question? *what if a thread completes before join is called? Does it result in an error? Is the return value lost?*

Comment: There's no error, and no return value is lost. It works just fine - so you could put the `$run = 0` line before the `sleep` line, and it'd all work just fine. (Just with fewer 'print' statements executed because the thread terminated earlier).

Answer (score 3):

All threads end when the program ends.  The program ends when the main thread ends.  The `sleep` in the main thread is merely keeping the program running a short time, after which the main thread (therefore the program, therefore all created threads) also end.

So what's up with `detach`?  It just says "I'm never going to bother joining to this thread, and I don't care what it returns".  If you don't either `detach` a thread or `join` to it, you'd get a warning when the program ends.

Comment: Wait, so even if a subroutine is still running the main programme would just end?

Comment: Yes. Which is why you pretty much never want to `detach` a thread in the first place.

Comment: And instead you'd want to use `join()` to wait for it to finish, correct?

Comment: If you want to ensure that a thread finishes what it's doing, then you would have to `join` to it (which means you can't have detached it).  The sample code shows what detached threads are good for - background processing that should go on as long as the process persists but that can safely be interrupted at any time.

Comment: I'd assert such circumstances are rare though - at the very least the effort involved in signaling for a clean exit and then joining is negligible. `perl` threading isn't well suited to short lived rapid spawning threads

Comment: I don't assume that a signal-and-join approach is always an acceptable substitute for detaching the thread.  (And neither does perl, which is why `detach` is an option.)  If to you it always is, that's fine; nobody forces you to use `detach`.

Comment: And yet perl _does_ pretty much always error and kill the thread if it's running when the main process exits. Unless it has already finished, but at which point the cost of `join`ing it was negligible.

Comment: And yet, so what?  You still don't know that every application is best served by doing things your preferred way, Perl still is expressly agreeing with my statement by providing the alternative way to do it.  So what's your point?

Comment: My point is, there are many possible ways to do things in perl, and not all of them are equally good ideas. "Perl lets me do it" is hardly a ringing endorsement of any coding style. If you detach a thread in this way, it is _likely_ because you haven't understood an important concept in perl threading, which is that they aren't lightweight. And that the number of scenarios where you genuinely don't care that a task even completes at all are extremely rare. If that is the case, then why are you bothering to do it in the first place?

Comment: So long as your argument remains that you can judge the value of a technique for everyone else's programs, I don't much care. My mistake for asking.